# react-native window.setInterval, trying to display an incrimenting number

Tags: react-native

I want to display a number that increases once every second, rather than using some kind of time function I am using window.setInterval because eventually I will replace this with some more complicated code that instead of just displaying the number calls some function and displays the result. Here is the code I have right now:

```
export default class Test extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state = {counter:0}
    }

    render(){
        newCounter = this.state.counter+1 // I am going to replace this
                                          // with something like:
                                          // newCounter = someFunc()
        func = this.setState

        window.setInterval(function(){
            func({counter:newCounter})
        },1000);

        return(
            <View>
                <Text>{this.state.counter}</Text>
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

It gives me this error: `undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.updater')`

how can I do this correctly? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
export default class Test extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {counter:0}
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    setInterval(() => {
        this.setState( prevState => ({counter: prevState.counter + 1}));
    },1000);
  }

  render(){
    return(
        <View>
            <Text>{this.state.counter}</Text>
        </View>
    )
  }
}
```

Basically, you want to use the function arrow with set Interval, to not lose the context of the `this` keyword, and try to use set State outside of the render method.

Here is a demo as well: https://snack.expo.io/HkikISZMm

Comment: thanks for the help however that didn't work, I got the an unexpected token error on the line with componentDidMount so I don't think I can use that function, also I looked it up and it seems to me that its deprecated however I might have missunderstood, here is the source: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html and and right after listing componentDidMount it says: `These methods are considered legacy and you should avoid them in new code`

Comment: This code should work. I have tested it. Please try it here: https://snack.expo.io/HkikISZMm . Also, in the docs, it is saying that `componentWillMount`, `componentWillReceiveProps`, and `componentWillUpdate` are unsafe legacy. `ComponentDidMount` is safe

Comment: It sounds like you have a syntax error also. Please try to copy and paste the above code

Comment: Thanks a lot! your completely right, I just didn't copy the code exactly, also thanks for pointing out that ComponentDidMount is safe, I wasn't clear on what the docs were saying so its good to have that straightened out

Comment: No problem! I’m glad I can help!